# Space in winscp script

Tags: winscp

I have an issue with WinSCP Script, I have a space in folder path. I am getting an error. I tried it double quotes, but I'm still getting an issue.

Withtout space it is working fine.:

```
set privatekeypath=c:\Projects\UploadScript\Privatekey\privatekey.ppk
set user=user
set path=/user
set scriptPath=c:\Projects\UploadScript\
set inputhPath=c:\Projects\UploadScript\Input\

%scriptPath%\App\WinSCP\winscp.exe /ini=nul /log=%~dp0\App\Logs\log_%datetime%.txt /command ^
    "open sftp://%user%@server.net/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa "" -privatekey="%privatekeypath%"" ^
    "cd %path%" ^
    "lcd %inputhPath%" ^
    "get *.* *.* -delete -nopreservetime" ^
    "close" ^
    "exit"
pause
```

With space in folder path:

```
set privatekeypath=c:\Projects\Upload Script\Privatekey\privatekey.ppk
set user=user
set path=/user
set scriptPath=c:\Projects\Upload Script\
set inputhPath=c:\Projects\Upload Script\Input\

%scriptPath%\App\WinSCP\winscp.exe /ini=nul /log=%~dp0\App\Logs\log_%datetime%.txt /command ^
    "open sftp://%user%@server.net/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa "" -privatekey="%privatekeypath%"" ^
    "cd %path%" ^
    "lcd %inputhPath%" ^
    "get *.* *.* -delete -nopreservetime" ^
    "close" ^
    "exit"
pause
```

I am getting the error "c:\Projects\Upload Script\" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried with double quote:

```
set privatekeypath=c:\Projects\Upload Script\Privatekey\privatekey.ppk
set user=user
set path=/user
set scriptPath=c:\Projects\Upload Script\
set inputhPath=c:\Projects\Upload Script\Input\

""%scriptPath%""\App\WinSCP\winscp.exe /ini=nul /log=%~dp0\App\Logs\log_%datetime%.txt /command ^
    "open sftp://%user%@server.net/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa "" -privatekey="""%privatekeypath%"""" ^
    "cd %path%" ^
    "lcd ""%inputhPath%""" ^
    "get *.* *.* -delete -nopreservetime" ^
    "close" ^
    "exit"
pause
```

Now I'm getting the error " The system cannot find the path specified.
Thanks for your support.